# How often should I clean the interiors of Playstation 5?

Tags: ps5

New to PS5. How often should I clean the interiors like fans and all ?

I don't want to clean it often, because I am afraid that I will damage the circuits. How often ? Every 15 days, 1 month or some other duration ?

Comment: Consoles typically can go months, even years without needing a cleaning - not that they *should* though. I think opening up your console would void any warranty typically. You may be ok with simply blowing some compressed air through the vents. Probably the more important thing you can do is keep the console in an area that's free of dust or at least cleaned often to reduce dust from being sucked in.

Comment: `simply blowing some compressed air through the vents` - That's what my meant by cleaning the fans. I am too afraid of opening the interiors

Comment: Ashis.... the PS5 is FAR superior to the PS4 in that regard. If you just remove the side cover you can clean the vent faucets without any risk to damage any circuit simply because you can't access any circuit in the first place. Also, removing the cover alone isn't going to void any warranty because that is the intended way to access the SSD expansion slot. Look at [this page](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps5-install-m2-ssd/) and watch the "How to add an SSD video to see what I mean".

Comment: Obviously one could try and go for some more invasive cleaning but on average you should be fine with this basic procedure, no real risk involved.

Comment: @Ꮢedacted I know that cleaning up is easier , but I still am too afraid to open the interiors. PS5 is my first console, and I am kind of emotional to it lol